# unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, int, nonetype

I am working on a project that I found online for a simple IP address to google maps conversation to find location for a simple car tracking process. There are 4 files in total but I am stuck on the main.py script. I have been trying to get it to work for days. I gave made progress but I am now getting the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,time,geolocation,publisher
from subprocess import call

SleepTime = 10 # seconds
_lat = 0.00
_lon = 0.00

def maintain():
    global _lat
    global _lon
(lat,lon,accuracy) = geolocation.getLocation()
if(lat != _lat or lon !=_lon):
    data = str(lat) + "," + str(lon) + "," + str(accuracy)
    print ("publishing") , data
    publisher.publishtoInternet(data)
    _lat = lat
    _lon = lon
else:
    print ("no change in coordinates")

print ("program begins")
while True:
try:
    maintain()
except Exception as inst:
    print (type)(inst), ('exception captured')
    print (inst)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    #file = open('/tmp/loctracker.error.log','a')
    #file.write('exception occured, trying to reboot')
    #file.close()
    #call(["sudo","reboot"])
#break
for i in range(0,SleepTime):
    sys.stdout.write ("\restarting in %d seconds ") % (SleepTime-i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Any help would much appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Can you fix your indendation please?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback please?

Comment: I disagree that a question about a TypeError is a duplicate of a question about an AttributeError, even if incorrect grouping caused both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
sys.stdout.write ("\restarting in %d seconds ") % (SleepTime-i)
```

Python thinks you are using the mod operator to do math on the result of sys.stdout.write (which is `None`) and `SleepTime - i` (which is an int). This is because you have an early parenthesis. What you wanted was to print the whole result:

```
sys.stdout.write ("restarting in %d seconds " % (SleepTime-i))
```

As a side note, % for formatting is [frowned upon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) in Python in favor of string.format.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
sys.stdout.write ("\restarting in %d seconds ") % (SleepTime-i)
```

you are using incorrect grouping. Here's what it's doing, illustrated with more parentheses:

```
(sys.stdout.write ("\restarting in %d seconds ")) % (SleepTime-i)
```

`sys.stdout.write()` returns `None`, and you're doing `None % integer`. You need to put `SleepTime-i` inside the call, so it applies to the string rather than to the function call:

```
sys.stdout.write("\restarting in %d seconds " % (SleepTime-i))
```